# What is permittivity at infinite frequency in cole-cole equation?

Tags: electromagnetism, dielectric

I am working with estimating the dielectric constant as a function of frequency. I did calculate the S-Parameters from Agilent VNA. The study is similar to [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7520546) 
When working this, i came across dielectric relaxation model in which there is permittivity at infinite frequency. Can someone help me how to calculate or deduce this.